# Deleting folders on git repository that were kept when I tried to manually rename

Tags: android, eclipse, git, bitbucket

In eclipse, I renamed my android project and pushed that to git repository...so now there's two different package folders for the same project. I can't figure out how to delete one of the folders. I'm using bitbucket.

Comment: You should add your own answer as proper answer and then accept it to "close" this issue.

Comment: @Kay Done. Kinda new to stackoverflow, thanks.

Comment: Almost! You still need to accept the answer. (: (It gets a green checkmark once that's done.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. I got back the directory locally and then I could remove properly with `git rm -r directory`